# What is the purpose of the 'and', 'or', etc. keywords in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-keyword, keyword

What is the purpose of the following keywords?

```
and      bitand   compl   not_eq   or_eq   xor_eq
and_eq   bitor    not     or       xor
```

If all they are is a direct equivalent of:

```
&&       &        ~       !=       |=      ^=
&=       |        !       ||       ^
```

Comment: Not all keyboards have `&`, `~`, `|`, etc. keys.

Comment: See [iso646.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h)

Comment: @Matt: although I have surprised a few coworkers, I generally prefer `not` to `!`. `!` is near invisible, `not` (which requires a space after it) stands out.

Comment: Your list is incomplete. The list of "Alternative tokens" (C++2003, §2.5) also includes `<%`, `%>`, `<:`, `:>`, `%:` and `%:%:`.

Comment: I'd love to use that more because imo it's much clearer (and looks at least a bit like python ;) ), but alas "write conventional, unsurprising code" pretty much excludes using those :(

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, "and", "or", and "not" are not keywords (§2.11). They are "*Alternative tokens*" (§2.5).

Comment: @Robᵩ:  Oh, of course they are!  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h

iso646.h *"...defines a number of macros which allow programmers to use C language bitwise and logical operators, which, without the header file, cannot be quickly or easily typed on some international and non-QWERTY keyboards.*

*The filename refers to the ISO646 standard, a 7-bit character set with a number of regional variations, some of which have accented characters in place of the punctuation marks used by C operators."*

Comment: And in C++ these are not macros, but 'alternative tokens', and you don't need to include iso646.h.

Comment: ...but it is a retarded solution as you still can't program C++ without the &, ~ and | characters even with these alternative tokens.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista Yes, you can. `int const bitand answer = 42;` is a valid variable declaration.

Comment: How do you define a destructor without ~? Or create a reference?

Comment: @RafaelBaptista `class foo { compl foo() {} };` not exactly readable... but it works.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista they're alternative **tokens**. They replace **tokens**, not semantic constructs. `int bitand` is *exactly the same as* `int &`.

Comment: Ugh. I'm corrected... sort of. Technically it works, but that is unusably broken. That kind of code would be an unreadable nightmare.

Comment: @R. If I ever have to obfuscate c++ code at the src level, I can only hope I'll remember this tidbit. Although MSVC++ doesn't support that feature.. and who can blame them? (g++ also doesn't completely, it allows if (foo and bar) though)

Answer (score 7):

Its so you can write crazy code poems like:

```
class jack
{
   jack();
   jack( jack & jill );
   jack& came_tumbling( int after );
   jack& fell( jack & jill ); 
   jack& operator &= ( jack & jill );
   jack& operator & ( jack & jill );
}

void to_fetch( int pail );

int a_pail;
int after;
jack broke_his_crown;
jack went_up_the_hill;
jack down;

jack and jill = went_up_the_hill;
to_fetch( a_pail ); // of water
jack fell( down and broke_his_crown 
and jill.came_tumbling( after ));
```

Comment: The poems I'd write aren't exactly appropriate for inclusion in our code repository ;)

Comment: We're all hoping that in c++12 they will add a token for Nantucket

Comment: The only problem with this snippet is that the `and` is equivalent to `&&`, not `&`... :P

Comment: Make this community wiki and it might become a C++ folk song :)